# Make the function input console.log with a for loop?

Tags: javascript

How do I convert this into a shorter for loop that works no with however many persons there are?

```
function greet(person 1, person2, person3) {
  console.log("hi " + person1);
  console.log("hi " + person2);
  console.log("hi " + person3);
}
```

Comment: Use an array and the typical methods/features used with an array

Comment: `function greet(...args) { args.forEach(person => console.log("hi " + person)); }`

Answer (score 1):

If this what you are looking for, You can pass n number of parameters when you call this function.

The function definition is using rest operator which converts all arguments as an array then you can run a forEach on it.

```js
function greet(...persons) {
persons.forEach(person=>console.log("hi " + person));
}

greet('abc','xyz','123');
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the function using JavaScript's Rest operator (`...`):

```js
function greet(...persons) {
 for(var person of persons) {
  console.log('hi ' + person);
 }
}

greet('Person 1', 'Person 2', 'Person 3', 'Person 4');
```

You can use it with as many parameters as you want.